# Windows 7 Backup System Restore problems

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup, windows-7-backup, vss

My mom's computer is acting up and it seems to tie back to VSS but i can't figure out what the problem is. It's a Dell running windows 7 Home Premium SP 1. 
The first symptom I noticed is that Windows updates take forever to run. I was home visiting and saw 20 or so updates wanting to install. I clicked the shutdown button to install updates and shutdown. The updates took hours to run. I think Windows is trying to create a restore point and the updates wait for it to restore. Installing or uninstalling any programs takes forever.

Now I'm looking at the application event log and there are tons of VSS errors in the log. Error codes 11, 12292 and 8193 are all found in the log.

when i go into the Backup and Restore from the control panel, it shows a red bar and an error message that says 'Check your backup. The last backup did not complete successfully'. Clicking 'More Information' pops up the "Set up Backup" dialog and that just gets stuck in a screen showing "Set up a Backup. Starting Windows Backup. Please wait while Windows Backup starts.". I eventually have to kill that off with task manager.

Running any vssadmin commands are very slow.

There were a few different backup utilities installed on the machine. A Dell backup system of some sort, which i just uninstalled. A Seagate system backing up to a USB drive that seems to be working on a weekly schedule. And last week my mom was talking to a Frontier (her ISP) tech who managed to sell her their cloud based backup system (based on F-Secure).

Before I re-install Windows, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would try and sort out the Windows updates first.  The backup sounds like a separate problem.

Comment: My feeling is that the backup problem causes the Windows update issue. Windows tries to create a restore point before installing updates and has to wait for that to fail or time out before it continues with the updates.